# Tomcat 8 Change Context Path from context.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, tomcat8

I am trying to deploy a web app in tomcat 8 where the context path should be different from the war file name.

We should be able to do this by adding a context.xml file in META-INF folder in web app according to [this tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html). I created this file with the following content, but this does not change the context path to mypath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/mypath" docBase="webapps/myWarWeb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" />
```

Tried changing the docBase value to `webapps/myWarWeb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, `myWarWeb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war` and `myWarWeb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` without any success.

Any idea on this?

Thanks,
Akalanka.

Comment: According to Tomcat 8 [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) on 'path' attribute this is not possible as I understand.

"This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase."

Answer (score -1):

Actually the tomcat8 documentation says you cant for the path attribute.

Concerning "path" it states: "This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase."